# Trimmed title field of teaser view using template.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to trim the title field of view.

title field comes from `"teaser view mode"` I want it using `template_preprocess_node`.

I used:

```
if ($vars['type'] == 'deals' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $vars['title'] = truncate_utf8($vars['title'], 30, TRUE, TRUE);
}
```

but it doesn't reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good to me.

Make sure in your `template_preprocess_node` definition, you have `&$vars` not just `$vars`.

Comment: Have you flushed the cache?!

Comment: can you paste the whole code; starting from you function definition?!

Comment: function deals_preprocess_node(&$vars) {                                             
  if ($vars['type'] == 'deals' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $vars['title']  = truncate_utf8($vars['title'], 10, TRUE, TRUE);
  } 
} this is my code. check it.

Comment: Change the function definition `deals_preprocess_node`. Replace `deals` with your theme's machine name and flush the cache.